# jQuery validation on tab can be bypassed using Firebug, is there a way to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, javascript-security

Security Question.
I have jQuery code which prevents a tab from opening. So if I click on any tab it gives me an alert 'Access Denied'.

```
    $('#tabs').tabs({
                  select: function(event, ui) {
                        var valid = false;
                        if(!valid)
                        {
                           // prevent further action
                           alert('Access Denied');
                           event.preventDefault();
                        }
                  }
              });
```

But as I can change script using Firebug or any other tool, I can set variable `valid` from `false` to `true` and it will allow me to access all tabs. Is there a way we can restrict this?

Comment: "Is there a way we can restrict this?" No, security logic must be coded server side.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do it using javascript, anybody can intercept and hack it using client side tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [Firefox Dev Tools](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2012/10/09/firefox-debuts-new-developer-toolbar/), [IE Dev Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview), [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) etc.

If you really wants to prevent somebody from seeing some tabs, you need to prevent its contents from server side. ie: the contents of the tabs should not be rendered to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you can't restrict this. You cannot provide security using any clientside scripting language such as Javascript. The Javascript is under the control of the end-user and thus it can be changed, you have to do it on the server-side; as at this stage you have control of the computer it's running on.